# C++ No matching member function for call to 'push_back' error for vector

Tags: c++

I have been working with a `vector` and I receive this error:

> No matching member function for call to 'push back'

Can anyone take a look at my code to detect my mistakes?

**bubble_jar.h**

```
#include "abstract_bubble.h"
#include "bubbles.h"
#include <vector>
#include "cpputils/graphics/image.h"

#ifndef BUBBLE_JAR_H
#define BUBBLE_JAR_H
class BubbleJar : public graphics::MouseEventListener,
                  public graphics::AnimationEventListener {
public:
  ~BubbleJar();
  void Initialize(int max_age);
  void Start();
  void OnMouseEvent(const graphics::MouseEvent& event) override;
  void OnAnimationStep() override;
  graphics::Image* GetImageForTesting() { return &image_; }

private:
  graphics::Image image_;
  int max;
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AbstractBubble>> ab;
};
#endif  // BUBBLE_JAR_H
```

**bubble_jar.cc**

```
void BubbleJar::OnMouseEvent(const graphics::MouseEvent& event) {
  std::cout << "BubbleJar got a MouseEvent" << std::endl;
  // Create a BigBubble on mouse press and a SmallBubble on mouse release
  // and add them to the vector.
  if (event.GetMouseAction() == graphics::MouseAction::kPressed) {
    BigBubble b(event.GetX(), event.GetY(), &image_);
    ab.push_back(b);  
    b.Draw();
  }
  else if ( event.GetMouseAction() == graphics::MouseAction::kReleased ) {
    SmallBubble s(event.GetX(), event.GetY(), &image_);
    ab.push_back(s);
    s.Draw();
  }
  image_.Flush();
}
```

Comment: `ab` contains `unique_ptr` but you are pushing objects not `unique_ptr`

Comment: probably because you're trying to pass a `BigBubble` as a `unique_ptr`?

Comment: so how can I push an object with unique_ptr?

Comment: unless you can convert bigbubble to unique_ptr, you can't push this object

Comment: how could I convert them ? is it in my .cc ?

Comment: Handy reading: [std::make_unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique). Use this to replace the automatic allocation of `b`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `std::vector` holds `std::unique_ptr` smart pointers to `AbstractBubble`-derived objects, but you are trying to push actual derived objects, not smart pointers to derived objects, hence the `push_back()` error due to a type mismatch.

Try this instead:

```cpp
void BubbleJar::OnMouseEvent(const graphics::MouseEvent& event) {
  std::cout << "BubbleJar got a MouseEvent" << std::endl;
  // Create a BigBubble on mouse press and a SmallBubble on mouse release
  // and add them to the vector.
  if (event.GetMouseAction() == graphics::MouseAction::kPressed) {
    auto b = std::make_unique<BigBubble>(event.GetX(), event.GetY(), &image_);
    ab.push_back(std::move(b));
    b->Draw();
  }
  else if ( event.GetMouseAction() == graphics::MouseAction::kReleased ) {
    auto s = std::make_unique<SmallBubble>(event.GetX(), event.GetY(), &image_);
    ab.push_back(std::move(s));
    s->Draw();
  }
  image_.Flush();
}
```